# How to install Subtitle Edit 3.3?

Tags: subtitle

I'm a subtitle translator in Sri Lanka. So, I used Subtitle Edit (http://www.nikse.dk/subtitleedit) in Windows to create/edit/translate subtitles into Sinhala language.

But, is it possible to install it in Ubuntu? I have the latest version of Ubuntu with all updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the Ubuntu compatible version here:

http://www.digital-digest.com/software/download.php?sid=1682&ssid=0&did=48

At the moment, this is 3.2 not 3.3 like you requested, but one user writes:

> This works well for me on Ubuntu, but my knowledge of Linux is rather small, so... ;)

The comments also suggest that the package requires Mono:
http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html

Comment: It said the file not found on server :/ (http://code.google.com/p/subtitleedit/downloads/detail?name=SE32Linux.zip)

Comment: Try this link instead: http://www.digital-digest.com/software/download.php?sid=1682&ssid=0&did=48

Comment: I've updated the link in the answer's text so not to misdirect anyone else.

Comment: Will you please help me to install the package "Mono" ? I'm a newbie to Ubuntu and I don't know much yet. I visited to the link as @danielhanly.com mentioned. But there is no download link for Ubuntu.
And please help me to install the Subtitle Edit also.

Comment: For people interested in writing/translating subtitles, I can also recommend `gnome-subtitles`. I've used this program in the past, and it can do everything I need it to do. :) You can install it by searching for *Gnome Subtitles* in the Ubuntu software center, or by issuing the command `sudo apt-get install gnome-subtitles` in a terminal (hit Ctrl+Alt+T to open a terminal).

Answer (score 3):

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04.2 64-bit.

Installing mono from Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

Download the **portable** version from https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit/releases.

Unzip the downloaded file and double click SubtitleEdit.exe.

Unlike other subtitle editors Subtitle Edit supports WebVTT (.vtt) files.

Comment: Does video play for you? In options, video is all greyed out for me.

Answer (score 0):

**`snap install`**

They now have a `snap` that just works https://snapcraft.io/install/subtitle-edit/ubuntu

```
sudo snap install --edge subtitle-edit
```

Tested on Ubuntu 20.10, that currently installed Subtitle Edit 3.5.